# Array Pivot center (Origin) - Modifier

Tags: modifiers, origin, transform-orientation

I have an array modifier and I want to center the pivot to the center of the array and not the object arrayed, is there a way to do that? [image]

Comment: probably not like this, array only sets your duplicates in one way... One possible solution would be to use 2 arrays, one will have positive value and one will have negative value of your center window

Comment: @MikoCG is right, either you do that or you apply your array and set origin to geometry.

Comment: thank you guys, I'm going with the 2 arrays method i find it more efficient and less time-consuming.